# Javascript Array Comparison

Tags: javascript

I saw one interview question .(i.e)
I have one array inside a function

```
function validate(){
    var array=["(","{","[","]","}",")"];
 }
```

Also i have one input field with submit button

```
<body>
<input type="text" name="equation" id="equation">
<input type="submit" name="check" value="check" onclick="validate();">
</body>
```

Now my doubt is when I enter input data as `{()}` it should display valid data in an alert.When I enter input data like `{()}]` it should display as invalid data.Which means for unbalanced input it should display `invalid` message.For that I need to compare array elements within an array.
How to do it?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This it not clear. What should the function `validate` do ? What have you tried ?

Comment: ` var a=document.getElementById('equation').value;
 var y=eval(a);
  alert("your answer is"+y);` <br>i just tried using eval.But this is not my question i need compare array values only unbalanced symbols .I don't know how to do it.

Comment: is this only for braces or there can be other input as well?

Comment: @MustafaMamun we can give input like `[(x+y)*(y-x)]` but it should check only braces value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the opened brackets and delete the last if the corespondent bracket is found. At last, check if the open bracket array is empty.

```js
function validate(s) {
    var open = [],
        brackets = { '(': 1, '{': 2, '[': 3, ']': -3, '}': -2, ')': -1 };

    return s.split('').every(function (a) {
        if (!brackets[a]) {
           return true;
        }
        if (brackets[a] > 0) {
            open.push(-brackets[a]);
            return true;
        }
        if (open[open.length - 1] ===  brackets[a] ) {
            open.pop();
            return true;
        }
    }) && open.length === 0;
 }

console.log(validate('([()()])'));
console.log(validate('(a+2)*4'));
console.log(validate(']'));
```